# Keycloak SAML redirection stuck in loop after logging in

Tags: java, tomcat, basic-authentication, saml-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to secure a url : `/monitoring` with Keycloak using SAML.

I've modified my web.xml :

```
<web-app>

    <!-- Javamelody Access check -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK-SAML</auth-method>
        <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>monitoringrole</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Monitoring</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/monitoring</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>monitoringrole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I've also modified my tomcat7's `context.xml` file with the correct Valve and added the keycloak-saml.xml in `/WEB-INF`.
I'm correctly redirected to the IdP, but even after successfully logging in, I keep getting this message : **You are already logged in**

I guess I'm redirecting to the same url I'm securing, but shouldn't keycloak grant me access to the page ?
[image: Keycloak screen after successfully logging in]

Here is my configuration on the keycloak server :
[image]

Am I missing something on the configuration side ?

Comment: Same issue here. Do you still got the problem?

Comment: Yes, and this made me switch to another SSO Provider : Okta.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016693/keycloak-stuck-in-loop-after-login). Went through the Keycloak logs to find `Info: Assertion expired`. In my case, `Keycloak` and `Service Provider (client)` are on different machines. The erroneous difference was that their system time was in different timezone.

The SP was creating `SAMLRequest` in UTC as per its timezone, and the `SAMLResponse` was coming in UTC as per different timezone.

So, maintaining same timezone fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue and i found the solution you need to define your Master SAML Processing URL correctly it is your client URL with saml (for eg. : http://localhost:8080/clienturl/saml) then it will work. Attaching the snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It resolved on changing the LOCALHOST to machine name