# Keycloak stuck in loop after login

Tags: servlets, keycloak, saml-2.0

I have setup `Keycloak` as an IdP for SSO using SAML2.0. I have registered my client at `Keycloak` with the needed URLs:
*Master SAML Processing URL:* `http://localhost:8085/myapp/saml`
Althought it's not necessary when I have the master URL set:
I have `ACS URL POST Binding`, `Logout URL POST Binding` both set to: `http://localhost:8085/myapp/saml`
`Root URL:` `http://localhost:8085/myapp`

When I try to access a protected resource i.e., a URL of the form 
`http://localhost:8085/myapp/protected/*`, `Keycloak` redirects me to its login page. Now, when I get a hit on my ACS URL after successful login, I try to redirect the page to one of protected resources. 
Doing this: `resp.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8085/myapp/protected/home.html");`.

Now, Keycloak again redirects me to login page and then gets stuck in an infinite loop.

My `web.xml` config is:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Keycloak Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.keycloak.adapters.saml.servlet.SamlFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Keycloak Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

-Some people got it resolved by ending the Master URL with `/saml` that I already have.
-I also tried putting `/rest` at the end of ACS URL, but nothing works

It just shows `Your are already logged in` or just keeps redirecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the Keycloak logs to find `Info: Assertion expired`. In my case, `Keycloak` and `Service Provider` (client) are on different machines. The erroneous difference was that their system time was in different timezone.

The SP was creating `SAMLRequest` in UTC as per its timezone, and the `SAMLResponse` was coming in UTC as per different timezone.

So, maintaining same timezone fixed the issue.